# Get Nested/Hierarchical Data from SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cte, hierarchy, recursive

I have a table relationship between 'Tag' and 'Task'. It is M:M. The relationship is mapped in the table '*TagTaskMapping*'.

The TagAssignment table stores the relationship between a Tag and a date. So a tag can be mapped to a single date(period).

I want to output a nested hierarchy from sql.

**SQL Tables:**

```
-- tag assigned to a specific date
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TagAssignment](
    [TagAssignmentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TagID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Period] [date] NOT NULL
);

-- task(s) mapped to tag(s)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TagTaskMapping](
    [TagID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskID] [int] NOT NULL
);

-- tag table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tag](
    [TagID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TagName] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL
)
```

**TagAssignment mapping table data:**

```
TagAssignmentID TagID   Period
24                3    31/05/2017
14                2    31/05/2017
```

**TagTaskMapping table data:**

```
TagID   TaskID
  2       1
  2       2
  2       3
  3       1
  3       3
```

Here is my **query**...

```
DECLARE @Period datetime = '2017-05-31'    
;WITH CTE_TagAssignment
AS
(
    -- GET TAG(S) Assigned to selected PERIOD
    SELECT 
         ta.TagID
        ,t.TagName
        ,null as 'Task'
    FROM dbo.TagAssignment ta
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Tag t
         ON t.TagID = ta.TagID
    WHERE ta.Period = @Period

    UNION ALL

    /**USING RECURSION!!!!**/
    -- foreach above tag assigned to a period, get it's associated task(s)
    SELECT 
        ttm.TagID
        ,null AS 'TagName'
        ,ttm.TaskID as 'Task'
    FROM CTE_TagAssignment cta
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.TagTaskMapping ttm
        ON cta.TagID = ttm.TagID
)  
SELECT *
FROM CTE_TagAssignment  
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);
```

However, I get this error: *The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.*

This is the hierarchy **output** I would like...

```
TagID   TagName   Task
2       Level 5 
                   1
                   2
                   3
3       Level 3 
                   1
                   3
```

Comment: Set maxrecursion to 0.

Comment: I tries this but my query is wrong somewhere. Runs an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you don't need a recursive solution, you can get it by using a simple JOIN.

> ```
> DECLARE @Period datetime = '20170531';
>
> SELECT     t.TagID, t.TagName, tm.TaskID
> FROM       TagAssignment ta
> INNER JOIN TagTaskMapping tm
> ON         tm.TagID = ta.TagID
> INNER JOIN Tag t
> ON         t.TagID = tm.TagID
> WHERE      ta.Period = @period
> ORDER BY   tm.TagID, tm.TaskID;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> TagID | TagName | TaskID
> ----: | :------ | -----:
>     2 | Level 5 |      1
>     2 | Level 5 |      2
>     2 | Level 5 |      3
>     3 | Level 3 |      1
>     3 | Level 3 |      3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=802adfa5fdacb6e4f6befe770b499687)*

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is basically a variation on McNets' solution, with the formatting you requested, and an explanation of the issue with your CTE.

As McNets notes, you don't actually have a recursive query. In a recursive CTE, the recursive part of the query normally has some condition on it that forces it to stop; it eventually encounters a set of values that generate no rows. Yours ahs no such stop condition; it's just going to keep generating the new rows repeatedly.

Your real problem is a formatting issue.

This should get the results you want, in the format you want:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Header = 1 THEN CAST(TagID as varchar(20)) ELSE '' END as TagID
      ,CASE WHEN Header = 1 THEN TagName ELSE '' END as TagName
      ,CASE WHEN Header = 1 THEN '' ELSE CAST(TaskId as varchar(20)) END as TaskID
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
               t.TagID, t.TagName, CAST(NULL as int) as TaskID, 1 as Header
          FROM TagAssignment ta
                 INNER JOIN TagTaskMapping tm ON ta.TagID = tm.TagID
                 INNER JOIN Tag t ON ta.TagID = t.TagID
         WHERE ta.Period = @period
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t.TagID, t.TagName, tm.TaskID, 0 as Header
          FROM TagAssignment ta
                 INNER JOIN TagTaskMapping tm ON ta.TagID = tm.TagID
                 INNER JOIN Tag t ON ta.TagID = t.TagID
         WHERE ta.Period = @period
       ) sq
 ORDER BY sq.TagID, Header DESC, sq.TaskID;
```

Check the [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7d6b5762415f74470f1504bcb80d748e) (again, based on the work done by McNets).